# If-else tag: Which of the following is true?

Tags: if-statement, blogger

Normally, the title html in Blogger will appear like this:

```
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
```

If one prefers post title before blog title, you get two types of conflicting codes after google search:

First type:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<title>
<data:blog.pageName/></title>
<b:else/>
<title>
<data:blog.title/></title>
</title>
</b:if>
```

Second type:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title>
<data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
<title>
<data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```

Which one is true?

Comment: Both of your code its true..

Comment: Want exactly do you mean? what should be the result/output? should it be one or the other, or both if possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about the new tag `<title><data:view.title.escaped/></title>`

Otherwise, both of your code is true but the second code is preferred if you want to show post title instead of blog title on both item and static page types (static page like "About").

Answer (score 0):

If you use first type title of item type return article title and for (static, archive, index, search, label) return the blog name.

If you use second type, the title index type (label, search and homepage) use your blog name and for (item, archive, static_page) use article title.

`data:blog.pageName` avaiable for item, static and archive, for item and static return article title and for archive page return date.